# Continuous Deployment with an ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session-state, continuous-deployment

I have a website in C#/ASP.NET that is currently in development.  When we are in production, I would like to do releases frequently over the course of the day, as we fix bugs and add features (like this: http://toni.org/2010/05/19/in-praise-of-continuous-deployment-the-wordpress-com-story/).

If you upload a new version of the site or even change a single file, it kicks out the users that are currently logged in and makes them start over any forms and such.  Is there a secret to being able to do deployments without interfering with users for .NET sites?

Comment: I think you need to change how you are storing sessions. I believe you need to go to file-based or sql-based storage. I believe you are current storing them inproc which I think stores them in the appgroup's memory space. Can't give any more details though, sorry

Comment: @hamlin, that's worthy of an answer.

Comment: how the application session is connected with forms authentication?

Comment: I mean, if the session was related with the authentication ticket a web farm would fail authenticating users unless you store the session in a common place and that's not true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make a change to a config file, the contents of a bin folder of the app, or things like that, the ASP.NET worker process restarts along with your application.

This results in deleted sessions and kicked-out users.

The solution is to use other session storage methods other than the default `InProc`.
You can achieve this by setting the [session state mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). The `SqlServer` and `StateServer` options provide very good remedy for your issue.

`SqlServer` mode is relatively easy to set up and get up and running. (Basically, it's just creating a database, running aspnet_regsql, and then specifying it to the config.) If you don't have MS SQL Server or don't want to use it, you can use `StateServer`, or create your own provider and use the `Custom` mode.

The only restriction is that you can only store serializable values with `SqlServer` and `StateServer` mode.

Comment: Agreed it's a session thing, and I realize I'm answering this long after the orig question (oh well). We ran into issues with SQL Server state deadlocking with larger traffic loads. We ended up going with Microsoft AppFabric Cache, which is what MS Azure uses. So far, that has been a solid solution for us.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you're seeing this is because you are resetting the application pool, thus resetting everyone's session.

The cleanest route would be to offload your session to a session state server, or minimize your use of session.

One way around this is if you can't offload your session is to always deploy to a new virtual directory. Your public facing URL then just redirects to your latest version. All users that are already logged in would continue to use the older version, but any new users would use the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose users are kicked because web-server application process is restarted. By default user sessions are stored in memory and session data is killed. Session provider is configurable option in web.config. May be choosing external (out-of-web-application-process) session provider is a step toward what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternatives to achieve that:

1. Do not use Session at all. (You may use cookies for authentication)
2. Use another Session-state mode. State server or SQLServer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=VS.80).aspx

Either way you will also gain the flexibility to be able to run your application on multiple servers for performance or fail safe clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you store in the Session object, you may be able to reconstruct it in Global.asax's Session_Start handler.  I used to do this in an internal application where we only really stored the user's identity in the Session, so we could just use their authorization cookie to recreate the session.

One thing to keep in mind if you do this: say a user loads up a form and then leaves for lunch, and you update that page while they are away.  If they return to their desk and submit the form they'll be submitting the old version of the form to the new code-behind.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but you'd have to do someting explicit and it would be a potential point of failure.  Maybe some kind of versioning of forms, so the form can see if the user is posting and out-of-date form to an updated code-behind.

Anyway, not something you have to worry about if you can't use the cookie approach anyway :)